# How convexity is related with weak lower semi continuity?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

If $R : H \to \mathbb{R}$  be a functional with $H$ be a Hilbert space. I want to  how convexity of $R$ (If it is convex) is related with weak lower semi continuity??

By definition weak lower semi continuity : Let $(x_n)_n$ a sequence such that $x_n \to x$ in $H$, then $x_n \to x$ weakly in $H$, then   $$R(x) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} R(x_n).$$ where topology on $H$ is weak topology.

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/439882/27978.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convexity plus (strong) lower semicontinuity implies weakly lower semicontinuity.

Just argue by using epigraphs: If $R$ is convex and strong lower semicontinuous, then its epigraph is convex and closed, hence weakly closed, hence $R$ is weakly lower semicontinuous.