# Is the functional $I(u) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^N}h(x) |u|^q \ dx $ weakly lower semicontinuous?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations, semicontinuous-functions, partial-differential-equations

Is the functional
$$
I(u) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^N}h(x) |u|^q \ dx 
$$
weakly lower semicontinuous for $N \geq 3$ and $1 < q < 2$?

This is part of an exercise that asks to solve the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
- \Delta u + u = h(x)|u|^{q - 2}u \quad \text{ in } \Bbb{R}^N, \\
u \in H^1 (\Bbb{R}^N)
\end{cases}
$$
where $1 < q < 2$ and $h \in L^{\frac{2^*}{2^* - q}} \cap L^\infty$ is nonnegative, using the method of minimization.

I showed that weak solutions are critical points of the functional 
$$
J(u) = ||u||^2 - \int_{\Bbb{R}^N}h(x)|u|^q \ dx.
$$

Now I am trying to show that $J$ is weakly lower semicontinuous and coercive. Coerciveness is easy, as is the weak lower semicontinuity of the norm. Hence, it remains to show that $I$ is weakly lower semicontinuous.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following works. Because [strongly lower semicontinuous convex functionals are weakly lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235380/mathcalf-convex-and-lower-continous-rightarrow-mathcalf-weakly-lowe?noredirect=1&lq=1), assume that $u_n\rightarrow u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Using the fact that $|a|^q\leq |b|^{q}+q|a|^{q-2}a(a-b) $, which follows from the convexity of $x\mapsto |x|^q$ we see that
$$h(x)|u(x)|^q\leq h(x)|u_n(x)|^q+qh(x)|u(x)|^{q-1}|u_n(x)-u(x)|$$
which implies that

$$I(u)\leq I(u_n)+q\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)|u(x)|^{q-1}|u(x)-u_n(x)|\,dx$$

If we can show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)|u|^{q-1}|u-u_n|\,dx=0$ then we are done by taking the liminf of both sides of the above. To see this, note that $|u-u_n|$ goes to $0$ in $L^{2^*}$ by Sobolev embedding, so we use Hölder's inequality
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)|u(x)|^{q-1}|u(x)-u_n(x)|\,dx\leq ||h|u|^{q-1}||_{L^{\frac{2^*}{2^*-1}}(\mathbb{R}^N)}||u-u_n||_{L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R}^N)}$$
which goes to $0$ as long as $h|u|^{q-1}\in L^{\frac{2^*}{2^*-1}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. But this is true because $|u|^{q-1}\in L^{\frac{2^*}{q-1}}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and
$$\frac{2^* -q }{2^*}+\frac{q-1}{2^*}=\frac{2^*-1}{2^*}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood almost everything. Could you only develop on the first inequality you claimed, please?

Comment: I edited to clarify this. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, it is very clear, but I instead referred to the fact $|a|^q \leq |b|^q + q|a|^{q - 1}(a - b)$. Could you show it as well, please? I can't see how to get to it from the convexity of $|x|^q$.

Comment: Oh I see. This is simply the fact that any convex function lies above its tangent line or in symbols $f(x)\geq f(y)+f'(y)(x-y)$. See here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable), for instance.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: My pleasure - this is an interesting problem. I hope what I wrote now is correct.

Comment: Dear @user293794, please, shouldn't it be $|a|^q \leq |b|^q + q |a|^{q - 2}a(a - b)$?

Comment: Also, in the last equation, it should be $\frac{2^* - q}{2^*}$, right?

Comment: Yes you are right on both counts. I will edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: The solution works, though. Thanks again :)