# continuous and convex imply the weakly upper semicontinuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, weak-topology

$X$ is a Banach space. $f$ is a function (may not linear) on $X$.We call $f$ is weakly lower semicontinuous if the set $\{x:f(x)≤c\}$ is weakly sequently closed.We call the set $A$ is weakly sequently closed if any ${x_n}$ belongs to $A$,$x_n$ weakly converge to $x_0$,then $x_0 ∈ A$.

1. Show that $f$ is weakly lower semicontinuous iff $x_n ∈ X$, $x_n$ weakly converge to $x_0$ implies $f(x_0)≤$the lower limit of $f(x_n)$.
2. $f$ is continuous (may not linear) and convex $$(0≤t≤1,f(tx+(1-t)y)≤tf(x) + (1-t)f(y))$$ imply that $f$ is weakly lower semicontinuous.

Comment: The property you are describing is usually called "weakly lower semicontinuous".

Comment: I will type it again.Thank you!

Comment: also the condition on the set should be $\{x:f(x)\le c\}$.

Comment: try to relate convexity/w.l.s.c. of $f$ to the convexity and closedness of the epigraph of $f$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2970746/convexity-and-strong-lower-semicontinuity-imply-weak-lower-semicontinuity?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for your reminding .I need to find the defining of strong lower semicontinuity.

Comment: Though space convexity makes closed and weakly closed coincide, I have no idea the convexity of a continuous f could make it weak lower semicontinuously